# Получить информацию физического диска на котором запущенна ОС

Tags: c#

Появилась задача на платформе **dotnet** (С#) получить информацию о жестких дисках машины и на основе этого прикреплять лицензию к железу.
Проблема в том, что при подключении внешнего жесткого диска (USB 3.0) или активации **RAMdisk**, то всё идет к чертям, так как у нас алгоритм работает только с девайсом с нулевым ID. Ибо по умолчанию, физический диск с ID 0 является загрузочным (с виндой).

Как можно получить информацию жесткого диска, на котором крутится запущенная ОС (серийники, размер, производитель)?

Comment: [Можно отсюда решение взять](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226851/how-to-lookup-hard-drive-model-with-c)

Comment: Не советую привязываться только к жесткому диску. Можете посмотреть вариант привязки к серийному номеру процессора, MAC и т.п.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004666/get-unique-machine-id http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030511.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь можно почерпнуть информацию как с железом работать:

```
[Win32_DiskDriveclass][1]
[ComputerSystemHardwareClasses][2]
```

И код для примера:

```
    public static (String SerialNumber, 
                   String InterfaceType, 
                   String Manufacturer, 
                   String Model, 
                   String Name) 
    GetHDDInfo()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
        (String SerialNumber, 
         String InterfaceType, 
         String Manufacturer, 
         String Model, 
         String Name) hdd = 
            default(ValueTuple<String, String, String, String, String>);

        foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] != null && 
                wmi_HD["InterfaceType"] != null && 
                wmi_HD["Manufacturer"] != null && 
                wmi_HD["Model"] != null && 
                wmi_HD["Name"] != null)
            {
                hdd.SerialNumber = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                hdd.InterfaceType = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
                hdd.Manufacturer = wmi_HD["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                hdd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
                hdd.Name = wmi_HD["Name"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return hdd;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

@БорисКрит  вы изначально идёте по неверному пути реализации  привязки. Кроме описанных вами моментов, могут быть и другие: файлы подкачки, виртуальные машины, динамический размер дисков для оптимизации системы, и много много другого. Допустим вы получите ID и другие параметры, пусть зашифруете, обфусцируете код, и все ваши усилия ничего не стоят, для .Net  запустим дебаггер и из него запустим ваш софт, отснифим обращения, и ответы сервера. Но это на первый взгляд сложный путь , есть проще - снимаем серийники машины на котором запущена лицензия, и пишем универсальный драйвер. На последок самое главное, что-бы вы себе не придумали от kernel32.dll не уйти. 
Вынесете логику на сервер, и авторизируйте пользователей по сессиям, ограничите пользователя одной или двумя сессиями.